# Update actionButton while performing a long calculation

Tags: r, button, shiny, loading

I have a `shiny::actionButton` which triggers a long calculation. I'd like to update the action button label that a calculation is being performed, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("button", "Calculate"))

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    print("start calculation")
    updateActionButton(session, "button", "Calculating...")

    # emulate calculation
    Sys.sleep(3)

    print("finish calculation")
    updateActionButton(session, "button", "Calculate")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But the button does not seem to change. It looks like the button just shows whatever was last `updateActionButton` and ignores anything before.

How do I make actionButton to update properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a progress set bar, instead of changing the button label.
E.g.

```
ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("button", "Calculate"))

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    #print("start calculation")
    updateActionButton(session, "button", "Calculating...")
    progress <- Progress$new(session, min=1, max=15)
    on.exit(progress$close())

    progress$set(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                 detail = 'This may take a while...')

    # emulate calculation
    #Sys.sleep(3)
    for (i in 1:6) {
      progress$set(value = i)
      Sys.sleep(0.5)
    }

    print("finish calculation")
    updateActionButton(session, "button", "Calculate")

    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage', message = 'Selected Points were set positive.')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

See more details here [reporting_progress](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/Progress.html).

Comment: How does that help the user of the application and how does that come close to answering my question?

Comment: This is an alternative solution, it may or may not fit you. As mentioned, above, instead of changing the label of the button during your calculation, you can use a separate progress bar, to show the progress to the user.